# Photo gallery with a CollectionView xcode

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an application that looks like a Photo Gallery.
I follow different references, but It still not run.
The problem is with the `imageView` in the cell, because if I try to change the backgroundColor of the cell it works, in spite of if I try to change the `image` of the `imageView` it doesn't run.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _ownImages = [@[@"1.jpg",
                    @"2.jpg",
                    @"2.jpg",
                    @"3.jpg"] mutableCopy];

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _photoGallery =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_photoGallery setDataSource:self];
    [_photoGallery setDelegate:self];

    [_photoGallery registerClass:[PhCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];

    [self.view addSubview:_photoGallery];

}
```

Here I change the option of the `CollectionView`

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _ownImages.count;
}
```

And finally, I create the `Cell`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PhCell *myCell = [_photoGallery dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    long row = [indexPath row];

    NSLog(@"%@", _ownImages[row]);

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:_ownImages[row]];

    myCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    myCell.imageView.image = image;

    return myCell;

}
```

To implement the custom Cell I create an `UICollectionViewCell` called PhCell. In this Class I set an xib file for the `cellView` in which there is an `imageView` connected to the variable

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;`

in PhCell.h

The code is free of errors, but it not display the image, why?

Comment: have you tried directly setting like: `myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_ownImages[row]];` ? and double checked if the `IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;` is hooked in storyboard?

Comment: yes, but It doens't run

Comment: I found the solution, the program doesn't load correctly the file xib so in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`  I load it correctly.  

`NSString *identifier = @"photoCell";
    
    static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;
    
    if(!nibMyCellloaded)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhCell"  bundle: nil];
        [_photoGallery registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
        nibMyCellloaded = YES;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to set the imagebackground is another color, like yellow, and let see the image is shown or not.

In the line `image = [UIImage imageNamed:_ownImages[row]];` I can see you have not inited the `image`.

Comment: It change color, so the image is not shown, I declare `UIImage *image;` like a global variable

Comment: Did you try this     `PhCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`, or did you check the image you use are correct or not, did you try with .png image files?